Getting 401 Unauthorized response for Apple Developer API call
I have implemented subscription purchase using Plugin.InAppBilling package and its codes are below.
private async void PlanClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("");
    if (IsBusy)
        return;

    IsBusy = true;
    try
    {
        // check internet first with Essentials
        if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet)
            return;

        // connect to the app store api
        var connected = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.ConnectAsync();
        if (!connected)
            return;

        UserDialogs.Instance.HideHud();
        //try to make purchase, this will return a purchase, empty, or throw an exception
        var purchase = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.PurchaseAsync(productId, ItemType.Subscription);

        if (purchase == null)
        {
            //nothing was purchased
            return;
        }

        if (purchase.State == PurchaseState.Purchased)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Purchase successfull");
            Debug.WriteLine("Purchase token:>>" + purchase.PurchaseToken);
            Debug.WriteLine("Purchase id:>>" + purchase.Id);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InAppBillingPurchaseException(PurchaseError.GeneralError);
        }
    }
    catch (InAppBillingPurchaseException purchaseEx)
    {
        // Handle all the different error codes that can occure and do a pop up
        Debug.WriteLine("purchaseEx:>>" + purchaseEx);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle a generic exception as something really went wrong
        Debug.WriteLine("exception:>>" + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        await CrossInAppBilling.Current.DisconnectAsync();
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}

After successful purchase I get the PurchaseToken and ID from app store and play store.
Now using this I need to fetch the subscription details of a user. Which App Store Developer API and Play Store Developer API are suit for this?
I tried using this API from Apple and this API from Play Store. Is this the correct API to fetch the subscription details?
When I try the Apple API I am getting the 401 Unauthorized response.
Using below code I am generating the JWT token.
private string LoadPrivateKey()
{
    string fileName = "API key (.p8 file)";

    using var stream = FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(fileName).Result;
    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    var privateKey = reader.ReadToEnd();

    // Remove the header and footer lines
    privateKey = privateKey
        .Replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", string.Empty)
        .Replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", string.Empty)
        .Replace("\n", string.Empty)
        .Replace("\r", string.Empty);

    return privateKey;
}

public async void JWTGenerator(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Key ID from Apple Developer account
        string keyId = "keyId";

        // Team ID from Apple Developer account
        string teamId = "teamId";

        // Load your private key from the .p8 file
        string privateKey = LoadPrivateKey();

        // Call the GenerateToken method to create a JWT
        string jwtToken = AppleApiTokenGenerator.GenerateToken(keyId, teamId, privateKey);
        DisplayAlert("JWT Token", jwtToken, "OK");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("JWTException:>" + ex);
    }

}

public class AppleApiTokenGenerator
{
    public static string GenerateToken(string keyId, string teamId, string privateKey)
    {
        byte[] privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iss, teamId),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Aud, "https://api.storekit-sandbox.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/subscriptions/{transactionId}"),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
    }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20),
            SigningCredentials = credentials
        };

        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        Console.WriteLine($"JWT token:{tokenHandler.WriteToken(token)}");
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
}

The .P8 file we have added under the Recourses/Row and set the build action as a MauAsset.
Can anyone provide a solution or guidance?
Thanks in advance for your help!

The official document said: "Unauthorized" means the JSON Web Token (JWT) in the authorization header is invalid. Did you read Generating JSON Web Tokens for API requests?

@Liyun Zhang - MSFT I have updated the question , can you please check ?

For iOS you would validate the subscription status on device using the StoreKit 2 framework.

This api can only get your app's Subscription Status not all the apps.

@Paulw11 When a user logs into the application, we obtain their purchase ID and purchase token. How can I check the user's subscription status using these details?

@LiyunZhang-MSFT I have updated the question with more details.

You can use the transaction identifier with that api.

are you doing this in the mobile app or on your server?  You should not use these APIs from the mobile app because you would need to have your secrets in the mobile app.

@Paulw11 We are doing it from mobile app and the secrets are available on the app side

You should not call these APIs from the app. Use the on-device APIs that are available. It is not secure to have the secrets in the app.

@Paulw11 What you mean by on-device APIs?

On iOS there is the StoreKit framework that can provide details on purchases. Presumably this is exposed to Maui by a package. We https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/

@Paulw11 We are using the same package for purchasing a subscription. After purchasing we are getting the token and id. With token or id we need to get the current subscription details like status, startdate or enddate. For that we are trying to call the app/play store developer API. Do you mean we can do this by inappbilling plugin?

Yes. You do not need to communicate with Apple is server. The device can tell you what subscription has been purchase and the expiration date. If you do want to query apple's server then you need to do this from your own server because you cannot store your private key securely in the app.

Unfortunately that plug-in uses the original store kit APIs. These are deprecated. StoreKit 2 is much easier to use and is recommended by Apple.  The original StoreKit APIs require you to check a receipt object that contains all transactions in order to find the currently valid subscription.  You can perform cryptographic verification on the receipt document.  The new APIs just give you the current entitlement with a single call and iOS ensures the validity of the purchase.
